# cocoa: read mail from Mail.app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to make an Mac application which read e-mails from Mail.app and display them, but I can't find any info about how to read mail from Mail.app. My question is:

1. how to read e-mails from Mail.app? any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applescript is probably the easiest way, for example:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to message 1 of inbox
    set theBody to content of theMessage as rich text
end tell
```

Run the script through `NSAppleScript`, quick dirty example (no error handling and so on):

```
NSString *theSource = @"tell application \"Mail\"\n"
"set theMessage to message 4 of inbox\n"
"set theBody to content of theMessage as rich text\n"
"end tell\n"
"return theBody";
NSAppleScript* theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:theSource];
NSAppleEventDescriptor* theDescriptor = [theScript executeAndReturnError:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", theDescriptor);
```

Alternative use `osascript` through `NSTask` to run the script.

**EDIT** (response to comment)

Loop through all messages and add their body to the `theMessages` list.

```
set theMessages to {}
tell application "Mail"
    set theCount to get the count of messages of inbox
    repeat with theIncrementValue from 1 to theCount by 1
        set TheMessage to message 1 of inbox
        set theBody to content of TheMessage as rich text
        set end of theMessages to theBody
    end repeat
end tell
return theMessages
```

Comment: See also scripting bridge, which will let you do this in ObjC: http://robnapier.net/blog/scripting-bridge-265

Comment: is there any way to get all mails? like `set theMessages to message all of inbox`?

Comment: You can loop through all messages get their content. Added quick example.